# I want to create a drop down menu with multiple drop down options

Tags: drop-down-menu

I want to create a drop down menu with multiple drop down options.
The form is looking like this.
County-->State-->City-->Place

Description:

1. In this form there is 4 drop downs
2. when the user select first one (country) other drop downs are acting simultaneously. when the user not select first one then other drop downs are disabled.
3. When the user select second one then remaining drop downs are acting simultaneously. when the user not select second one then remaining drop downs are disabled.
4. When the user select third one then last drop down is acting simultaneously. when the user not select third one then last drop down is disabled.
5. finally select last one option and then click Button

then there is a display of place attribute like some details about that.

Example:
Select your country(after selection)
Select your state(after selection)
Select your city(after selection)
Select your place(after selection)
after selection display some data about that place.

Comment: which language do you use?

Comment: Sheets of paper and a lot of string should do.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried till now? Which language have you used or want to use? If this is for a website, then are you using a CMS? If yes, then which one? Provide details and the codes that you have tried.

Comment: looking like this (http://coursesweb.net/ajax/multiple-select-dropdown-list-ajax_t) but i need 4 drop downs. language is php, mysql, javascript

Answer (score 0):

Please post some more details about the language and platform that you are using.. Also try to brief us on your status on these problem as in how far you have been able to implement the functionality you have mentioned and where exactly are you stuck..!!

All the best..!!

Comment: using language is php with mysql and/or javascript